# Finding the needle in haystack by adding one until needle is found

Tags: php, math

I have this array of random numbers created by a table in database

```
$numbersArr = array(3,5,17,19,24,30,38,...)
$userInput = 35;
```

So far this is what I have

```
if (in_array($userInput, $numbersArr)){

 echo 'found needle';

}else{

//add one to the $userInput until find a needle

}
```

So the program would add 1 to 35 until it found 38, then stop. How can I do this? I'm pretty sure it's straightforward but I cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: I assume this is just an exercise but just in case it is not, do you aware that the suggested algorithm is very inefficient and there are much faster ones to solve this task?

Comment: @SergGr: Yes it is a simple exercise to learn. But I'm opened to your ideas. Mind showing what you're talking about? :-)

Comment: Steven, PHP is not even my third language (I came here from the `math` tag) and you can see my discussion with Dave under his answer. If JavaScript is OK for you, take a look at the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3jg2cr/1/). Otherwise Andreas' solution is not perfect but is still much better than your plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for looping.
You can filter the array, and echo min number.

```
$numbersArr = array(3,5,17,19,24,30,38,12,15,21,67);
$userInput = 35;

// Filter array, return values larger than user input
$filtered = array_filter($numbersArr,
    function ($value) use($userInput) {
        return $value >= $userInput;
    }
);
If(count($filtered)>0){
    // Echo smallest number in array
    Echo min($filtered);
}else{
    Echo "no number larger than user input";
}
```

Try it here: https://3v4l.org/fMg7K

Comment: Nice approach, and it handles floats too +1

Comment: Really? I didn't even think about that. Thanks! Not sure it's what OP wants though. Some people just like looping.

Comment: Loops aren't necessarily bad if used efficiently. One thing I noticed which might make your callback even better would be to use a ternary operation instead of the`if` statement, for example: `echo( $filtered ? "Needle: " . min($filtered) : "Number exceeds maximum" );`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple for loop:

```
$numbersArr = array(3,5,17,19,24,48,74,30,38);
sort($numbersArr);
$lastNumbr = end($numbersArr);
$userInput = 35.5;

if ($userInput <= $lastNumbr) {
    for ($i = ceil($userInput); $i <= $lastNumbr; $i+=1) {
        if (in_array($i, $numbersArr)) {
            echo 'found needle: '. $i;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "input number out of range, must be below " . $lastNumbr;
}
```

This takes the `$userInput` value and adds 1 to it until it reaches a needle in `$numbersArr`. This will also handle floating point numbers by rounding them up. Numbers that are beyond the high number in the array return an "out of range" message.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you have asked but I'm wondering what your goal actually is because it doesn't seem like doing this would be useful.

```
$numbersArr = array(3,5,17,19,24,30,38,47,52);
$userInput = 35;

if (in_array($userInput, $numbersArr)){

 echo 'found needle';

}else{


    for ($loop = $userInput;$loop < 9999999; $loop++) {

        if (in_array($loop,$numbersArr)){

            echo 'found needle';
            break;

        }

    }  // end of for loop

}
```

Comment: The search would have to be between the given numbers in the array. The maximum number can't be 999999. It has to be the last number of the given array.

Comment: If the user input can be arbitrary it should not matter where the loop ends. It either will or will not find something.

Comment: @Dave, there are numbers bigger than `9999999`. @Steven, if the array is known to be sorted, I think you should take a look at l'L'l's solution

Comment: The range of numbers possible in user input wasn't specified but you are correct, if a value supplied is larger than that it will fail. That was an arbitrary which could be changed or, as suggested, take a look at the solution l'L'l provided.

Comment: @Dave, I fundamentally don't like this kind of code: it contains an arbitrary exit condition as if it was known to be OK but it just is not. I'd say the code would be OK if you a) explicitly handled the case that the loop ended without finding anything or b) used an infinite loop or c) used `PHP_INT_MAX` for your exit condition  (or better still use a + c together to be ready for corrupted input data).

Comment: I agree @SergGr ... I was addressing the original question. The answer by Andreas is elegant to say the least!

Comment: @Dave, I don't agree about Andreas as well. It doesn't use the described algorithm. And if the goal is performance then it is still very inefficient: you don't need `array_filter` to find just one element. If you want performance - just iterate over the array and keep track of the minimum element bigger than `$userInput`. In the worst for Andreas case where `$userInput` is small this will be much much faster.

Comment: @SergGr you are correct that looping the array is the fastest method. https://3v4l.org/v9og4

Comment: @Andreas, IMHO that's pretty obvious because if you use filtering you have two sources of significant overhead: 1) creating new array of filtered items (which also means more memory pressure and eventually more GC) 2) Iterating over that array for the second time. Also a minor optimization in my code (see comment under the question) is checking for the case where exact value exists and doing early exit from the loop. Using a good compiled language this should be faster because the same comparison is used in two `if`s so in assembly it is fast. Not sure if this is better or worse in PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$numbers = array(3,5,17,19,24,30,38,41,47);
$guess   = 35;

$limit = max($numbers);
while($guess <= $limit && !in_array($guess, $numbers))
    $guess++;

var_dump($guess);
```

Output:

```
int(38)
```

Comment: (Note to self: brilliant interview question.)

Answer (score 0):

SergGr is actually correct, it is faster to just loop the array and compare the item with user input.

This is what I found the fastest method.

```
$match = false;
Foreach($numbersArr as $item){
    If($item >= $userInput)
        If($item < $match || $match == false)
            $match = $item;
}
Echo "\n\n" . $match;
```

See results here: https://3v4l.org/v9og4